# Google BigQuery run query within PHP app?

Tags: php, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently trying to learn how to use Google's BigQuery library for PHP. I have the connection setup but now want to attempt to query some of their test tables. Is there a way within the BigQuery library that I can query a database with SQL?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the [sample PHP code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/src/functions/run_query.php) for running a query linked from the [querying data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#bigquery-sync-query-php) topic in the documentation? It sounds like that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I got the code working but... my permissions are all messed up. Now I'm waiting on my boss to set them and it should hopefully work.